# formula to calculate geo-referencing paramerters

Tags: georeferencing, dotspatial

I am trying to overlap the vector and raster data. I have two control points on both raster and vector data. Now I want to generate world file parameters for overlapping two data. I am using DotSpatial (github DotSpatial) as an base library for rendering the GIS data.

My control point on raster image are: `(x1,y1) and (x2,y2)` and control point on vector data are: `(u1,v1) and (u2,v2)`.

How can I generate the required parameters programmatically?

Parameter details are [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/world-files-for-raster-datasets.htm)

I need something like below

[image]